# Send an inputted image to the server from the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

**This post was closed incorrectly - one of the two questions linked didn't actually have an answer and the second's answer was what I have tried, as stated below**

I have an HTML file input element and can access the input using

```js
const image = document.querySelector('#image-input').files[0];
```

I then want to run a POST request using JS Fetch to the server. I do this using the following function:

```js
export const addImage = async(imageTitle, image) => {
        try {
                const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/addImage/`, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: {
                                imageTitle,
                                image
                        },
                        headers: {
                                'content-type': 'application/json'
                        },
                });

                ...

        } catch (e) {
                ...
        }
};
```

I then receive this on the server-side:

```js
app.post('/api/addImage', async (req, res) => {
        const imageData = req.body;

        console.log(imageData);
});
```

But when I print out the `imageData` I get:

```
{
        imageTitle: "some title",
        image: {}
}
```

Why is this image empty?

**What I have tried:**

- Changing the content-type to 'multipart/form-data' and using the `FormData` from JS.
- Leaving the headers blank / setting the content-type to `undefined` - the problem here is that I require `application/json` otherwise the entire `req.body` seems to be empty on the server-side.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?